# How to plot all R squares of a list of models in a single plot in R?

Tags: r, list, plot, regression

This is an example df. However my original df is much more big.

```
ind1 <- rnorm(99)
ind2 <- rnorm(99)
ind3 <- rnorm(99)
dep <- rnorm(99, mean=ind1)
df <- data.frame(dep, ind1, ind2, ind3)
```

Following code is to run 3 models to each variables in the df.

```
ind <- c("ind1", "ind2", "ind3")
fmt <- c("dep ~ %s", 
         "dep ~ poly(%s, 2, raw=TRUE)", 
         "dep ~ poly(%s, 3, raw=TRUE)")
fo.strings <- c(outer(fmt, ind, sprintf))
outputs <- sapply(fo.strings, lm, data = df, simplify = FALSE)
```

The outputs is a list of models (9 list in total).

I want to plot Rsquares of all models in the list in a single plot and 
order them lowest to highest to compare them. It is quite complicated when they are in a list. It would be highly appreciated if someone help this out.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You extract the R squared with `summary(model)$r.squared`, and you can apply that function to the list. I'll use `sapply` here so the output is a named vector. Then there are many ways to plot it, you could use base R plot functions or ggplot, but an easy one is `lattice::barchart`:

```
rsq <- sapply(outputs, function(mod) summary(mod)$r.squared)
rsq <- sort(rsq)
lattice::barchart(rsq)
```

Comment: @astrofukswag. How should i select only significant models from this list?

Comment: Do you mean a significant F-statistic from ANOVA? http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/extract-the-p-value-of-F-statistics-from-the-lm-class-td885076.html

Comment: I mean to select the significant models at p<0.05 and remove others

Comment: The most straight-forward interpretation of a "significant model" would be a significant F-statistic, which is mathematically equivalent to ANOVA and is part of the default output from `summary(lm(...))`. So check out that link I sent and try to turn that into a function you can `lapply` or `sapply` over your list of models